# How to include/install mod_proxy_http.c on JustHost

Tags: htaccess, apache

I'm using a service that requires a URL to be sent to their site so that it can return an HTML snapshot to Googles crawlers. In their .htaccess code it has the line

```
<IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
```

and it doesnt make it past that statement (implying that I dont have that module installed/enabled?) But the service says that most servers should have that installed. I tried contacting JustHost but havent received a response yet so was hoping you could help. I dont know much about this stuff so I dont know where to begin but on JustHosts cPanel it doesnt seem to let me into their httpd.conf which is where most resources are saying to fix this. It does however let me add things to the "Apache Handler" but frankly I have no idea how.

Comment: Is this shared hosting? It may be best to wait to hear from tech support for exact advice. I also strongly recommend pursuing the question here too. As of right now, I do not have advice for you. Normally these things are specified within the httpd.conf or apache2.conf files. Also, mod_proxy is a significant security risk that most hosts disable short of a dedicated server.

Comment: phpinfo() is a quick way to find out a lot about your hosting environment.  Look in the Loaded Modules section to see which Apache modules are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be surprised if they had mod_proxy enabled on their shared hosting servers. The amount of abuse that would open them up to would be quite high.

If you are on your own VPS instance then you can simply log in as root and issue the "a2enmod proxy_http" on debian/ubuntu and then restart apache.

http://www.justhost.com/vps

Comment: Yah I forgot to add a comment that I got in contact with them and they said exactly what you did. Not available on shared I'd have to get a VPS.